# External Repository Changes

Tags: svn, version-control

I use svn:externals to reference several open source projects. I then make some local changes to one of these external projects. Obviously I cannot check these changes back into the external repository. How do I keep these changes in my repository while still maintaining the ability to easily incorporate external changes?

Git makes this quite easy, but I use Subversion, so I am looking for an SVN friendly way to do this. (I use Tortoise SVN client against a 1.5+ SVN server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case it's still relevant, and for future users: I think you want to maintain your changes to the external project in a ['vendor branch'](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).

- import a copy of the external code into a separate project in your repository
- create a branch of it in your own project, to which you can add your own modifications
- regularly, you update the project's code in the original branch so you can merge these changes into your own branch.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using svk locally.  I believe you can continue to pull remote changes into your local repository but have changes you never push back.

Comment: What is svk? How do I save the changes that I dont push back?

Answer (score 0):

I support [jeroenh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329843/external-repository-changes/1156028#1156028)'s answer above since you are using an "SVN Friendly" way to maintain external code.

svk is not a solution as you cannot commit what you've changed to the external repos. If you use svk, you might as well just edit the external code in svn...just don't commit them.